# Inconsistency in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to obtain scatterplot in matplotlib. I'm using version 3.3.4 of matplotlib in jupyter notebook.
However, I cannot get a figure with solid fill. I tried using both '.' and 'o' as marker, the result is similar.

My code:

`plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c='k', s=0.1, marker='.')`

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the scatterplot has hollow circles with a dot inside. Is this a known issue? any remedy to this?

Comment: `s=0.1` is probably to blame. `s**2` is the size of the marker **in points**. How many points do you think is 0.01? I assume MPL gets confused.

Comment: Yeah. I also got it. Using s=1 i got the desired result, it looks worse in notebook, however, after saving the image with high DPI it's okay. Now I have to update a lot of my figures.